# Get all nuget packages in solution

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to write a unit test to enforce consolidation of Nuget packages (we have a build requirement that all unit tests pass so this would keep PRs that aren't consolidating from passing) and I was attempting to use `Nuget.Core` to do that. However, I cannot seem to find my way through their libraries and no one has asked this question yet. So, how can I get all the Nuget packages a given solution references programmatically?

Comment: Check this answer on how to use NuGet.Core to read packages.config https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046897/920557

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the final solution (along with unit test). The key is to use the `Directory` library to iterate over all the projects in the solution and then use `NuGet.Core` to analyze the NuGet packages in each project.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NuGet;
using Shouldly;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class NugetConsolidationTest
    {
        private List<string> _ignoredPackages = new List<string>();

        [TestMethod]
        public void AllNugetPackagesAreConsolidated()
        {
            var packageVersionMapping = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            var parentDir = (Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent).Parent.FullName;
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(parentDir, "packages.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var packageFile in files)
            {
                var file = new PackageReferenceFile(packageFile);
                var refs = file.GetPackageReferences(true);
                foreach (var packageRef in refs)
                {
                    if (_ignoredPackages.Contains(packageRef.Id))
                        continue;
                    if (!packageVersionMapping.ContainsKey(packageRef.Id))
                        packageVersionMapping[packageRef.Id] = new List<string>() { packageRef.Version.ToFullString() };
                    else
                    {
                        if (packageVersionMapping[packageRef.Id].All(x => !x.Equals(packageRef.Version.ToFullString(),
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                            packageVersionMapping[packageRef.Id].Add(packageRef.Version.ToFullString());
                    }
                }
            }

            var errors = packageVersionMapping.Where(x => x.Value.Count > 1)?.
                Select(x => $"Package {x.Key} has {x.Value.Count} separate versions installed! Current versions are {string.Join(", ", x.Value)}");
            errors.ShouldBeEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was brilliant thank you. I used it to make a CSV file for opensource software used in a project.... but i'm also going to use this test in all projects from now on too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always read the package.config files and parse them.

The one that's inside the solution directory with reference other packages.config file is one for each project contained in the solution.