# List installed NuGet Packages in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, nuget

I am looking for a way to list all NuGet libraries I have (manually) in ASP.Net Core 2.2.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621882/8089994) for .NET in general which involves parsing the `packages.config`. When launching via IIS however, the executable is in a completely different directory, preventing me from easily accessing the file.
Another option was to [get all assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710073), but this includes `System.*` assemblies and custom assemblies I do not want to display.

Comment: Why not just look at the list of packages in your .csproj file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035704/how-to-read-the-list-of-nuget-packages-in-packages-config-programatically

Comment: @LGSon .NET Core projects use PackageReference, not packages.config, so that question isn't applicable.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain any PackageReferences coming from `Directory.Build.props`, or any other `<Import`ed MSBuild file will not be listed there. Or if it is listed in the proj, you may use a property value as the version. So, reading the csproj as an XML file has many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the output of [`dotnet list package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package). I think it can be done with 3 or 4 regexes. There's ongoing, but low-priority work to [make it work with packages.config projects](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8209) projects, and there's already a [request to make the output more easily parsable](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7752).